# How to get a "Maximize" button in every window in GNOME Fallback

Tags: 11.10, gnome, window-buttons

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10 (AMD64), and immediately switched back to GNOME with GNOME Fallback.

I'm searching for a feature which provided a "maximise" button in *every* window, even ones which should have only the "close" button.

In older Ubuntu versions this feature was activated when switching from "None" to "Normal" in "Visual Effects":

[image: Screen shot of older desired functionality]

But now, that window is out, and I can't find that feature. I guess it's somewhere in CompizConfig, but I've searched there with no result.

Does anyone know what's the feature I'm searching for?

Comment: If you don't want desktop effect at login select gnome classic

Comment: This isn't a compiz thing it's a gnome3/shell/mutter thing, so I've retagged your question

Comment: @EngelsPeralta That *is* what he's using.

Comment: yeah my bad sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can set this feature with `gconf-editor`:

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gconf-editor`
2. Use the left tree view to navigate to `apps` -> `metacity` -> `general` -> `button_layout` or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and enter `button_layout`.
3. You see several settings in the right top window. Click right of `button_layout`. Now enter `close,maximize:`
4. Your settings are automatically saved when you leave the text field.
5. Now you should have a close and maximize button on every window (But when the developer of some interface didn't want to have a maximize button, there is no way to put one there).

If you also want a minimize button, type `close,minimize,maximize:` at point 3 above.