# No Title Bar button to close window Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, titlebar, window-buttons

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 from Ubuntu 16.04, the titlebar buttons on the upper left corner of the window for closing, minimizing and maximizing windows have vanished.

[image]

Then I went to **GNOME Tweaks** (GUI menu) --> *Windows* --> *Titlebar*
and set the options to add maximize and minimize buttons to the title-bar. However there was no option for Window close button there:
[image]

Things I have tried to correct this

1. I installed gconf-editor and tried this [gconf-editor solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79946/how-to-get-a-maximize-button-in-every-window-in-gnome-fallback/120368#120368)
2. I did not understand the solution (if any) [provided here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54866/no-close-button-in-gnome-3)

Output of the command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

Output: `'minimize,maximize'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your window-control button layout doesn't look right. Run the following command in Terminal to reset it

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

This should fix the problem. If it doesn't work, then set a suitable button layout manually. For example run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

to get the minimize, maximize, close buttons (in this order) at the right end of the title-bar.

Alternatively to get the close, minimize, maximize buttons (in this order) at the left end of the title-bar, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout close,minimize,maximize:
```

and so on.

Comment: Still works for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: this worked only once I enabled "Use system title bar and borders" in chrome appearance settings, for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Things have evolved since then. The solution will likely be a modification of the solution using gconf-editor you referred to. The key nowadays lives in a different place.

Install dconf-editor. Navigate to the key org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout. Switch the "Use default value" toggle to "On". The value should become `:appmenu,close`. If your default would be different (since you upgraded rather than performing a fresh install), then manually enter the value `:appmenu,close`.

Comment: Installed `dconf-editor`, ran it in the terminal, but it is unclear how the options you have specified need to be edited from the menu-tree I get on running:
-apps
-ca
-com
-desktop
-org
-system

Comment: Can `dconf reset -f /` fix this?

Comment: **Warning:** the command suggested by @mido above would reset *all* your GNOME settings (customisations you have done).

Comment: @pomsky yeah i would suggest backing up settings `dconf dump / > settings.txt` before resetting